# PayPal IPN verification update

Tags: paypal

I have a message from PayPal saying that on one of my sites I must ensure that HTTPS is used for the verification postback. Another site, with identical code, has not received such a message and works with Sandbox which I thought meant that verification was correct.

My code is as follows. Do I need to change it?

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n"; 
$header .="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the email said you should be posting back to https your line $fp should look like this -

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

Hope this helps. I have had a nightmare few days dealing with IPN.